# get Image Name in ImageView Android

Tags: android

I am dynamically loading images in image view by setting

`view.setBackgroundResource(cards[i])`

// cards is the image array

```
cards[] =   {R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2....}
```

is there any way I can know the image name or image id associated with image view in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name of a resource like

getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage);

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("us","drawable","com.app");
```

The above function will return an integer value same as R.drawable.us.

This is how you access with resource names.

To access the resources name

```
String resName = getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.imagename)
```